# CORS: Why my browser doesn't send OPTIONS preflight request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

From what I've read about [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), I understand it should work as follows:

1. Script on a client side tries to **fetch a resource** from a server with **different origin**.
2. Browser intercepts this request and first makes **preflight OPTIONS request** to the same URL.
3. If **response** to this preflight request contains **appropriate headers** (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`), browser understands it's allowed to send main request and does it.
4. Response is returned to the client script.

I've set up a test for it like this:

- server in Go accepting both - GET and OPTIONS requests (checked using CURL) - and setting `Access-Control-*` headers in response
- simple HTML page (served by another server on another port) with the following script in it (`$` stands for jQuery):

  ```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://local.site.com/endpoint,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  });
  ```

When I call this method, however, I see only one GET and no preflight OPTIONS request in the Network tab in both - Chrome 49 and Firefox 33.

Here are details of my GET request from Chrome:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:local.adform.com
Origin:http://localhost:7500
Referer:http://localhost:7500/test-page.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

and corresponding response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 03 Aug 2016 10:53:19 GMT
```

Any thoughts on **why** my browser(s) **don't send preflight request**?

Comment: preflight is not always done, less likely (if at all?) with a GET - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for when preflight is required

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for more info on when a browser issues a preflight request.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thanks for remark. If preflight request is not always required, what is the (conventional) way to overcome "same-origin" policy? The scenario is: we create a script that will be incorporated into 3rd party websites and will send us _our_ cookies? As far as I understand, without preflight request browser won't send cookies to our servers, right?

Comment: see the next section in the doc I linked - [request with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: I would recommend reading the whole page - it's informative

Comment: @JaromandaX: thanks for suggestion, that was an interesting reading. I've eventually made it working and will post the method as an answer.

Answer (score 20):

As pointed out by commentators, with GET **browser doesn't always send preflight OPTIONS request**. If preflight is indeed needed, one way to make browser to send it is to set custom header (e.g. "X-PINGOVER: pingpong" or whatever). Note, that server should also allow this *request header* by adding it to "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" *response header*.

---

My underlying goal was to pass **cookies** with domain `a.com` to servers of `a.com`, but from a page of another site(s) `b.com` (common use case for this is tracking your users on 3rd party websites). It turns out to send cookies alongside the request a bit more work is involved.

On *the client side* (i.e. in JavaScript) one needs to enable cross domain request and allow passing credentials. E.g. the following request with jQuery worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true           // allow passing cookies
  },
  crossDomain: true,                // force corss-domain request                
  success: function (data) { ... },
  error: function (request, error) { ... }
});
```

On *the server side* one needs to set 2 response headers:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <requester origin>`

where `<requester origin>` is protocol + host + port of a website that performed a call. Note, that generic `*` may not work in many browsers, so  it makes sense for server to parse `Referer` header of request and respond with specific allowed origin.

Comment: See [MDN Preflight Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) docs for more info.

Comment: It's important to note that your server may not be expecting "X-PINGOVER" as a header and it may return an error.  To address this, in your server code, where you set the value  of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, include `X-PINGOVER`