# Laravel VueJS, Axios can't see CORS header but Postman and Browser do

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, http-headers, cors

Let's get on with it.

## BRIEF INTRODUCTION

When making the Axios GET request to my API I am getting cors issue like this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/my-endpoint/' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

## WHAT I HAVE

I have my separate VueJs app running and Laravel 7 app on Docker on port 8080. I know for a fact that my endpoints are working 100% fine. I also using [Laravel cors package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors).

## CORS PACKAGE CONFIG

```php
paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

## WHAT I CAN SEE IS HAPPENING

When I take a look at response headers from my Laravel endpoint from Postman or from Chrome they both contain the following:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

So by the looks of it, the header is there and it is attached and to the response.

## PROBLEM

The problem here is that for some reason it is not visible at all when Axios makes a call.

Does anyone know what can be happening here? I did try different solutions from all StackOverflow pages I could find but nothing seems to be working.

I do understand that I must be missing something silly here, some piece of setup, or some config somewhere.

## EDIT 1:

I am not sure if I am supposed to see this but I can't see Axios making the preflight request therefore I can't see if `Access-Control-Request-Method` header is being sent. I am not sure If I am supposed to see that but I can see that is what Laravel package is looking for in the middleware.

Comment: I'm seeing different ports at the URL the first is `8080` while the other one is `8081`, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @Makdous - this is how it's supposed to be. I have my backend Laravel app running on local Docker port 8080. The front end app when I run it with `npm run dev` starts up on localhost port 8081 because docker is already using 8080. Both apps are working just fine on their own. It is just this CORS issue. They can't communicate.

Comment: @Makdous P.S Unless this is the issue with Docker or something. However, I see people on Youtube also use ports like that so I think this is not the issue.

Comment: In the chrome dev console network tab you're *supposed* to see the OPTIONS request. If you can't see it then (for some reason) axios didn't send it. Try another browser as well in case there are any plugins interfering

Comment: @apokryfos - That is very interesting. It "sort off" works in Firefox Developer Edition. I am saying sort of because I believe that this browser probably ignores CORS by default. I did a test. I sent a request with and without the CORS package enabled on the API backend. Both worked fine. When I had CORS package enabled I can see CORS HEADERS What is interesting I can always only see one request. The request to the actual endpoint. OPTIONS request is not made at all. Is that something I should do manually? Or you think it is jus AXIOS not working?

Comment: @apokryfos Just to add... I also just checked if it somehow depends on the method and no, it does not. No matter what method I use, POST or GET nothing seems to be working. Maybe I should tell Axios somehow that "Hey you are making CORS request, send OPTIONS!" ?

Comment: The browser "version" of axios wraps around a [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) so in the end it's up to the browser if a preflight request is going to be sent. For some reason the browser seems to be determining to not send one in your particular case. Not sure why,  normally if you have different ports even if it's the same IP it should send it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to apokryfos (see comments under my question) I came up with the answer. I wasn't easy and I am still not sure if this is a way to go.

I hope this will help other people.

So first I looked at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742379/cors-why-my-browser-doesnt-send-options-preflight-request) post.

## THE ACTUAL PROBLEM I HAD

The real problem was not setting CORS which was done correctly from the very beginning.

The real problem was that chrome was not sending the CORS preflight request.
What is a preflight request? Good question. I will answer that soon.

## THE SOLUTION I MANAGED TO FIND

Let's start with understanding what CORS PREFLIGHT REQUEST really is.

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
>   CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific
>   methods and headers.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:
>   Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the
>   Origin header.
>
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser and in normal
>   cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests
>   themselves. It appears when request is qualified as "to be
>   preflighted" and omited for simple requests.

So normally browser will ommit OPTIONS CORS preflight request for [SIMPLE REQUESTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

Now my current development environment (and maybe production one once I will finish my work on that system) has `npm run dev` running on `localhost:8081` and my Laravel backend API is running on Docker on `localhost:8080`

This is why I am always going to need a [CORS PREFLIGHT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) request. I am always going to need that request because at least for the development I will always have my backend and frontend app in conflict with CORS policy.

## CONCLUSION

I am still not sure if it is the correct way to go about it but it kinda makes sense. At least I am not blocked anymore with my work.

**Of course, CORS settings I have in my questions will be changed to more secure once I am done. I don't think it's a good idea to allow anything from anywhere!**

Answer (score -4):

I had got the same CORS error while working on a Vue.js project. You can resolve this by disabling the security settings of your browser (eg, CHROME) for accessing cross origin apis. This solution worked perfectly for me. This solution does not require any mock server or a proxy server to be built.

You can disable the **CHROME security settings for accessing apis out of the origin** by typing the below command on the mac terminal:

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security

After running the above command on your terminal, a new chrome window with security settings disabled will pop up. Now, run your program (npm run serve or npm run dev) again and this time you will not get any CORS error and would be able to GET request using axios.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very bad practice I'm afraid. By doing this you are only hiding the problem which will pop up later on. This is something that needs to be taken care of not ignored.